# How can i increase dedicated RAM for Android Studio Emulator?

Tags: android

When i created virtual device for the first time there was an option to choose how much RAM we want to dedicate to device. I want to increase it now but i dont know how.

Comment: This is already been answered many times, you should google it first. However check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this images: 
[image: First Step]

After clicking edit option,
[image: Second Step]